# Lock-free sharing of data with a single mutator in Rust

Tags: rust

**Context**

As an exercise, I'm attempting to re-implement https://github.com/urbanairship/sarlacc-pit in Rust.

Sarlacc-pit mirrors an external source into an in memory data structure (Set/Map/Etc). Clients of the library operate purely in terms of the collection with no knowledge that its contents are changing under the hood.

**Problem**

Clients need to keep an immutable reference to the collection, while a single update thread keeps a mutable reference in order to update its contents. This directly violates rust's guarantees but should be safe in this case with the following rough structure:

```
pub struct Map<K, V> {
  delegate: SomeReferenceType<Arc<HashMap<K, V>>>
}

impl<K, V> Map<K, V> {
  pub fn get(&self, k: &K) -> Option<&V> {
    self.delegate.borrow().get(k)
  } 

  fn update(&mut self, new_delegate: HashMap<K, V>) {
    self.delegate.set(Arc::new(new_delegate));
  }
}

pub struct UpdateService<K, V> {
  collection: Arc<Map<K, V>>
}

impl<K, V> UpdateService<K ,V> {
  pub fn get_collection(&self) -> Arc<Map<K, V>> {
    collection.clone()
  }

  // Called from a thread run on a cadence
  fn update_collection(&mut self) {
    let new_value = /* fetch and process value from backing store */
    self.collection.borrow_mut().update(new_value);
  }
}
```

This doesn't compile for a number of reasons, I realize.

The core of the question is: What should the type of SomeReferenceType be to allow to allow these mutable and immutable references to co-exist without something like an ReadWriteLock? Am I missing something?

Comment: I really didn't understand a thing. You can't have a mutate reference and a immutable reference in Rust period It's UB whatever the situation.

Comment: Data races are UB, certainly, but the mere co-existence of mutable and immutable references doesn't guarantee races, just makes them possible. It seems like this courts a dangerous territory, but should be possible by some use of UnsafeCell.

Comment: no, it's UB period, UB is UB, Rust clearly state that just the create of it is UB. Please, don't confuse java like language that make it "safe" with rust life language where UB is a thing. Rust make assumption that this can't happen, if it happen you have UB. Note that it's can't happen without use of unsafe. If this kind of magic solution where really working programming would be easier. But magic don't exist. You can't read and write something in the same time it's unsafe and unlogical.

Comment: @Stargateur this is a matter of terminology. You are right about _references_, but I would assume that OP would be satisfied with some kind of smart pointer or wrapper around raw pointers, which won't necessarily trigger UB.

Comment: @PeterHall "The core of the question is: What should the type of SomeReferenceType be to allow to allow these mutable and immutable references to co-exist without something like an ReadWriteLock?"

Answer (score 2):

If `update_collection` is called from another thread, what guarantees do you have that the main thread isn't in the middle of reading from the collection at the same time? With the information you have provided, you need something like a `RwLock` or `Mutex` to make this safe.

You have asserted that you believe this to be safe. If there is an undisclosed constraint on your system that allows you to guarantee that a simultaneous read and write cannot happen then there may be a way to incorporate that into the types. But a better answer can't be given otherwise.

For example, if updates are infrequent, it might satisfy your use case to use three copies of your collection, and swap them over after each modification:

1. One for reading,
2. One for writing,
3. One for transitioning clients while swapping the collections

This would not be a "beginner" level Rust project though.

Comment: It's guaranteed that only one thread will hold a mutable reference to the collection because it's owned by the update thread.

There is no guarantee that a read and update won't overlap, the point of the question is how to make that safe without locking. If it would halp I can illustrate how this works in the java version to show that it can be safe in *some* language.

Comment: @CoryKolbeck If you mean [this](https://github.com/urbanairship/sarlacc-pit/blob/master/sarlacc-client/src/main/java/com/urbanairship/sarlacc/client/structures/container/UpdatingCollection.java#L8) it's essentially using a locking structure because of the `synchronized` method. It's equivalent to using a `RwLock`.

Comment: Updates are infrequent, generally every 10s at most frequent. In your example wouldn't you still need shared state with a single mutator to perform swaps?

Comment: To be safe, you'd still need to coordinate across threads with atomic counters or similar. The third copy is to avoid the need for blocking. I believe your Java code will block if a read and write overlap — though I'm not a Java expert so I could be wrong there.

Comment: The analogue in the java version is here: https://github.com/urbanairship/sarlacc-pit/blob/master/sarlacc-client/src/main/java/com/urbanairship/sarlacc/client/structures/container/UpdatingSet.java#L12

The lone update thread executes `set()` operations on this atomic reference, where any readers issue get()s. There is no guarantee that the reference won't be swapped out while a reader is somewhere in the guts of the previous collection, but that is fine.

Comment: (those set and get operations claim no locks, they rely on assignment/dereference being atomic by nature)